# Sqlite cursor.getCount() crashing app when ran

Tags: android, sqlite

This code seems to crash my app every time it runs but data is stored in the data base and can be extracted anyone know why?

```
 public int getContactsCount() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
       Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
       cursor.close();

    // return count
    return cursor.getCount();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you do cursor.close(), all the resources for cursor are released so you are trying to getCount on something that is not there.

Answer (score 1):

Dude!  You closed your cursor!

Comment: This is the first real answer that I've seen that could also pass for a movie title. Nice job